# How to sort react components based on props being passed into it

Tags: reactjs

I have this component SingleEmail that I pass props into such as emailSubject, emailFrom, emailDate, emailBody. I am trying to figure out how I can sort ascending and descending for the dates which are in a format like 4/8/2020.

I setup

```
  <Sort by="emailDate">
            <div className="IncomingArea">
              {this.state.data.map((value, index) => (
                <SingleEmail
                  Subject={value.emailSubject}
                  From={value.emailFrom}
                  Date={value.emailDate}
                  Body={value.emailBody}
                />
              ))}
            </div>
          </Sort>
```

a component named Sort wrapped around my SingleEmail component which is this

```
// Sort.js

import React from "react";

// Compare function needed by the Sort component
const compare = (a, b) => {
  // you can access the relevant property like this a.props[by]
  // depending whether you are sorting by tilte or year, you can write a compare function here,
};

const Sort = ({ children, by }) => {
  if (!by) {
    // If no 'sort by property' provided, return original list
    return children;
  }
  return React.Children.toArray(children).sort(compare);
};

export default Sort;
```

and basically I am trying to figure out where to go from here to get this to be able to sort by date asc and desc based on the emailDate values. I have two buttons setup on the page with the SingleEmail component so I can add an onClick for both one for asc and one for desc. Just confused on how to get this sort component to supply states or whatever is needed so I can use them to sort with if that makes sense. Any help would be appreciated =] Hopefully this is not too general of a question =p

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure why you need the `Sort` component when you can just sort the data that you have using the standard Array's sort method.

> Note that you need to cast the strings into Dates objects in order to compare them:

```
data.sort((a, b)=>{return new Date(a.emailDate) - new Date(b.emailDate)})
```

Here is how your code should look like:

```
<div className="IncomingArea">
    {
        this.state.data.sort(
            (a, b) => {
                return new Date(a.emailDate) - new Date(b.emailDate)
            }).map((value, index) => (
            <SingleEmail
                Subject={value.emailSubject}
                From={value.emailFrom}
                Date={value.emailDate}
                Body={value.emailBody}
            />
        ))}
</div>
```

Comment: No, why do you need this inside the onclick of a button? Did you check the of my answer?

Comment: My bad that was a dumb question haha

Comment: Did you see my react example? two lines below the javascript one-liner. You have it all there...

Comment: ugh today is just not my day lmao idk how I missed that thanks man